# How does JavaScript (asynchronous) determine what things to "wait" for before proceeding?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise, q

I'm working with JavaScript a lot lately and I'm trying to figure out how the interpreter determines when to "wait", and when to move on to the next line of code asynchronously.

Take these two code examples. Read my comments for my confusion.

1:

```
function doAThing(thing, callback) {

    var someBoolean;

    if ( !thing ) {
        someBoolean = true;
    } else {
        someBoolean = false;
    }

    // Calling the callback function only happens *after* the above if statement,
    // meaning the interpreter waits instead of just calling it immediately?
    callback(someBoolean);
}
```

2:

```
function doOtherThing(thing, callback) {
    var someBoolean;

    // Some fake ORM, querying a fake DB with a where clause of thing
    Model.find().where({ someProperty: thing }).exec(function(err, results){

        if ( results ) {
            someBoolean = true;
        } else {
            someBoolean = false;
        }

    });

    // Calling the callback function happens *immediately* and does NOT wait for
    // someBoolean to get a value inside the ORM query above before it proceeds,
    // so the callback function is given an undefined value for someBoolean 
    callback(someBoolean);

}
```

- In the example 1, why / how does it wait for the if statement to be fully executed before calling the callback function?
- How do you determine what things JavaScript is going to "wait" for, vs things that it's not going to wait for?
- What are some strategies to handle this control flow more elegantly in native javascript, without the use of libraries such as Q, Async, etc?

I probably have some of this terminology wrong, feel free to correct me. I'm here to try and understand it and appreciate any advice. I'm also interested in reading any resources pertaining to JavaScripts asynchronousness but don't know where to look.

Cheers!

EDIT: I understand that in example #2 I can "force" the callback to only be called when someBoolean has a value by placing the callback call at the end of the ORM query. However that can often get unwieldy very easily. Here's example #3:

```
function doSomething(thing, callback) {
    // Some fake ORM, querying a fake DB with a where clause of thing
    Model.find().where({ someProperty: thing }).exec(function(err, results){
        ModelTwo.find().where({ somethingElse: thing }).exec(function(err, results){
            ModelThree.find().where({ somethingElse: thing }).exec(function(err, results){
                ModelFour.find().where({ somethingElse: thing }).exec(function(err, results) {
                    // Tons and tons of nesting, getting ever-more-confusing
                    // and pushing my code further to the right....
                    callback();
                });
            });
        });
    });
}
```

That is a very convoluted example, but I have ran into situations like this before working with Node. It gets very messy very fast when I have to run multiple queries on a DB or interact with some external service multiple times, at the end of which I need to call the callback...

I guess my question is: in native javascript, is there a better way to avoid all of this nesting nonsense, or should I just use a promise library like Q or Async?

I'd like a control flow more like this, in native JS:

```
function doAThing(thing, callback) {
    var bool1, bool2, bool3, bool4;

    SomeLib.someAction().exec(function(err, results){
        bool1 = false;
    });

    SomeLib.someOtherAction().exec(function(err, results){
        bool2 = true;
    });

    SomeOtherLib.action().exec(function(err, results){
        bool3 = false;
    });

    SomeOtherLib.delete().exec(function(err, results){
        bool4 = true;
    });

    // I'd like this only to be called when the above 4 actions are complete,
    // **without** nesting all of the actions together and calling the
    // callback at the end of the last one. As far as I understand it now...
    // I will need a library like async or q in order to have a
    // control flow like this?
    callback(bool1, bool2, bool3, bool4);
}
```

Comment: *"n the example 1, why / how does it wait for the if statement to be fully executed before calling the callback function?"* it doesn't wait, it executes in order. example two doesn't wait either, it executes in order. The difference is in example two the callback of .exec() is executed by .exec after some action has occured, such as a setTimeout.

Comment: Passing a function as an argument does not mean it's called. This is a pretty special thing in Javascript that you must get used to. Read this : http://jszen.blogspot.ca/2008/07/function-reference-vs-function-call.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Err, JavaScript is completely syncrhonous. None of your code examples involve any "decision" on the behalf of the interpreter as to whether or not to wait; there is *no* waiting involved. Every statement in both examples will execute in order without being interrupted. Some functions block, and some don't, but this isn't up to the interpreter.

> ```
> if ( !thing ) {
>    someBoolean = true;
> } else {
>     someBoolean = false;
> }
>
>
> // Calling the callback function only happens *after* the above if statement,
> // meaning the interpreter waits instead of just calling it immediately?
> callback(someBoolean);
> ```

If the function blocks, it blocks. You don't have to worry about it, your code just proceeds in order of execution from top to bottom.

> ```
> var someBoolean;
>
> // Some fake ORM, querying a fake DB with a where clause of thing
> Model.find().where({ someProperty: thing }).exec(function(err, results){
>
>     if ( results ) {
>         someBoolean = true;
>     } else {
>         someBoolean = false;
>     }
> });
>
> // Calling the callback function happens *immediately* and does NOT wait for
> // someBoolean to get a value inside the ORM query above before it proceeds,
> // so the callback function is given an undefined value for someBoolean 
> callback(someBoolean);
> ```

That's correct. You should instead invoke `callback` inside the function you're passing to the ORM. You need to invoke the callback when the results are ready, that's the whole point of callbacks. Your function doesn't need to invoke its callback immediately, that would defeat the purpose.

> How do you determine what things JavaScript is going to "wait" for, vs things that it's not going to wait for?

By reading the documentation. If it accepts a callback function, that's probably how it's going to communicate a value to your code.

> What are some strategies to handle this control flow more elegantly in native javascript, without the use of libraries such as Q, Async, etc?

... What do you mean? You pass it a callback function. If you want to get more complex than that, you should use a library, such a Q, Async, etc.

Comment: So in example #2, my only solution would be a library like Async / Q in order to have the ORM query fully execute before executing the callback?

Comment: I understand that that would solve my issue in this particular case, but what if I have to do a half dozen nested things and I don't want it to get unwieldy? I am adding an example #3 above in a sec...

Comment: Then use a library which provides an abstraction like promises. What's your problem with doing so? You can post as many examples as you like, but my answer won't change. You either pass your method a callback function, or you use a library which abstracts that away, or you write your own library which abstracts that away.

Comment: Added example #3 -- I have nothing against using a library like async or q -- I am basically just asking if there was a way to handle any of that stuff in native JS (that won't require unwieldy nesting) instead of having to use a library. Thanks for your answer :) I'll just use a lib.

Comment: @user3541693 promises are native now, also look at Bluebird promises and `Bluebird.coroutine` for linear code without nesting

Answer (score 1):

Read into how events work, because everything asynchronous in js involves events and event listeners. It has nothing to do with just passing callbacks as arguments and then calling them inside the function.

Asynchronous code works like this:

- A function registers an event listener and an event handler and then it's done and returns
- When the event it listens to fires the event handler goes to the end of a list of code that gets executed in a single thread, one by one in the order they occur.

Imagine all your code you run as a single thread, one line of execution. Any event listener you register in that code gets executed after everything else in your init code is done, there is no way for it to execute somewhere in between, just like two events can't get handled at the same time.

All your examples do is leading the thread around a few corners, funneling it around a function, maybe making a knot but they are not really "breaking out" of that thread. If you on the other hand just use

```
setTimeout(yourCallback,0);
```

then you are suddenly asynchronous. Your callback will go to the end of the waiting line and will have to wait until every single part of your current code is executed and there is "nothing else left to do" so it can go to the next in line waiting or idle, waiting for events to fire.

Comment: Well, event listeners *are* callbacks :-)

Comment: Oh you're right. This just blew my mind a little bit since i've never though about it that way :)